# Get cell paragraph without losing the current style

Tags: python-docx

So, I got this func running

```py
def get_bold_lines_from_cell(cellColumn, cellRow):  
    for index, paragraph in enumerate(table.cell(cellRow, cellColumn).paragraphs):  
        for run in paragraph.runs:  
            if run.bold:  
                #do stuff
```

Even though the paragraph is filled with bold paragraphs it just doesn't recognize any. Does it loses it style because I've turned a docx into tables? is there anyway to get the paragraph style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anybody ever have the same problem, this is the solution that I've came up with

```
for table in tables:
    cell = table._cells[cellNumber]
        for paragraphIndex, paragraph in enumerate(cell.paragraphs):
            for parentParagraphsIndex, parentParagraphs in enumerate(paragraph._parent.paragraphs):
                for run in parentParagraphs.runs:
                    tempString =  parentParagraphs.text.encode('utf-8')
                    if run.bold:
                        #do stuff
                        break
                    elif run.style.style_id == "Strong":
                        #do stuff
                        break
                    else:
                        #do stuff
                        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to look at the XML for each object to find clues.

```
print paragraph._element.xml
print run._element.xml
```

If there's a style applied you'll see it in the `w:pPr` or `w:rPr` element.